# Converting Nonetype into String

Tags: python, string, function, nonetype

I have this code which returns a `Nonetype`, when I thought it would return a string. And I have been trying to find solutions on stack, but I am yet to find one.

Here is the code:

```
members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline']
visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']

def check_group(members, visitors):
    for person in visitors:
        if person in members:
            print(f"Member present: {person}")
            break
    else:
        print("No members visited")
```

output:  `Member present: Danny`

Answer (score 0):

You have forgottent a `s`in when typing `members` line 2.
Also, your code won't return anythings, just print the value you asked it to print.

Comment: I didn't need them with the 's', but if it helps you. the 2 parameters are called (member,visitor) and the lists are (members,visitors) i added the S's if it makes it easier to read for you. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a question of readability. Your code was referencing variables that weren't set.

Comment: no the parameters, were named intentionally. and it was still read prior to adding a 's', so I don't understand the point.

Comment: If you execute the first version of your code you'll get a `NameError` because your variable `visitor` called in the for loop is referenced nowhere.

Comment: I Don't understand because the original works and i do not get a name error

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return statement.
So if this is part of a function then it should be something like this

```
def find():
    members = ['Alex', 'Danny', 'Kieran', 'Zoe', 'Caroline'] visitors = ['Scott', 'Helen', 'Raj', 'Danny']

    for person in visitor:
        if person in member:
           print(f"Member present: {person}")
           retrun person 
        else:
           print("No members visited")
    return None
```

Comment: Sorry @Rohit, This doesn't return the necessary output.